# App TemplateDoesNotExist in Django Project

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am struggling to figure out why I am receiving the `TemplateDoesNotExist` error in my project.

This is my initial project layout. The project name is localassets, the initial app name is assetlist.

[image]

I have registered the app in my `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'assetlist.apps.AssetlistConfig',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_bootstrap_icons',
    'django_extensions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'localassets.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

I have successfully created views and templates within this app and it displays all templates without issues.

I now want to add another app to this project. This app is named `workorders`. I created the app the folder structure is shown below:

[image]

I have also registered this app in the project `settings.py` file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'assetlist.apps.AssetlistConfig',
    'django_tables2',
    'django_filters',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'django_bootstrap_icons',
    'django_extensions',
    'crispy_forms',
    'crispy_bootstrap4',
    'workorders.apps.WorkordersConfig',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


ROOT_URLCONF = 'localassets.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

My issue is that I have created a template `tenant_list.html` and a generic list view:

```
class TenantListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Tenant
```

`workorders\views.py`

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="hello"),
    path('tenants', views.TenantListView.as_view(), name='tenants'),
]
```

I receive a `TemplateDoesNotExist` error when trying to access the url `workorders\tenants\` and I'm not entirely sure why the project can't access or find the template within the workorders app, am I missing something from within the `settings.py` file?

Comment: Templates should be inside templates/{app_name}/ directory. Create a folder with your app name inside templates folder and move all your html files inside that folder

Answer (score 0):

The **TemplateDoesNotExist** is showing because the template directory is set empty.

In your settings it is set like this => 'DIRS': []. You missed to add path to your template.

I request you to please go through the django template tutorial.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/templates/

Answer (score 0):

For a [**`MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectTemplateResponseMixin), of which `ListView` inherits, it will look to `appname/modelname_list.html`, so in a directory with the name of the app of the model.

This thus means that you place the template at:

```
workorders/templates/workorders/tenant_list.html
```

so you add a subdirectory named `workorders` in the `templates` directory.

The app subdirectory is common for Django's builtin generic views like `DetailView`s, `UpdateView`s, `CreateView`s, etc.

Answer (score 0):

create a subfolder inside templates folder and put html pages in it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).